# Spring boot how to receive param value from command line with space?

Tags: spring-boot

Spring boot how to receive param from command line with space?

```
@Value("${paramJson}")
private String paramJson ;

@Override
public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(paramJson);
}

./target/spring-boot-foo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --paramJson="{price: 30}"
```

it output `{price:`

So if command param value have space, how to receive it correctly?

Comment: Works for me with Spring Boot 1.3.5.RELEASE. Can you provide a complete, minimal example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson please see https://github.com/zhugw/spring-boot-read-command-param

Comment: I'd missed that you are building a fully-executable jar rather than running with `java -jar`. It works with `java -jar`. The problem must be in the launch script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [a bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5942) in the script that Spring Boot prepends to a fully executable jar file. This bug causes it to mishandle quoted arguments. The problem only occurs when the jar is executed directly. If it's started as a service via init.d, quoted arguments are handled correctly.

You have a few options:

1. Run the application using `java -jar`
2. Install the application as an init.d service
3. Wait for Spring Boot 1.3.6.RELEASE that will contain a fix for the problem
4. Use a [custom launch script](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.5.RELEASE/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html#embeddedLaunchScript) and correct the problem yourself